# NuGet does not execute scripts when restoring packages

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Nuget does not execute scripts when restoring packages in a project.

Here's the scenario: I have a project that has a custom NuGet package installed.  This project has NuGet Package Restore enabled for the solution.  This all is working flawlessly, which I tested multiple times by getting the project from TFS onto a empty folder.

I've added init.ps1 and install.ps1 to the nuGet package, and the package is still fetched and installed properly, but the scripts do not execute unless the package is installed manually.

To be exact, if I get the project from TFS for the first time, neither init.ps1, nor install.ps1 executes.

However, if I close the solution and reopen it, init.ps1 executes (as expected), but, of course, install.ps1 still doesn't since the package has already been restored/installed.

Both scripts execute normally when the package is installed/uninstalled manually (i.e. it doesn't run if the package is "restored").

My internet searched haven't turned up any references to this behavior.  Am I missing something obvious, or is this normal when packages are restored?

Comment: Package restore is simply restore, not install. I think this is by design. http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2728

Comment: Thanks for the link - that's my conclusion as well.  I didn't realize the intent behind init.ps1.  As for install.ps1, that makes sense, I think, since the package is, in fact, already "installed" - it's just missing from the project folder, hence the "restore".

Answer (score 1):

The Package Restore feature is used so that not all the packages are checked into source control.  As such the only thing that it does is pull down the NuGet packages into your `./solution/packages` folder so that the assembly paths and references can be correctly resolved at build.  NuGet does not do a re-install as part of restore, meaning that it will not do any xml file transforms or run the PowerShell install/uninstall scripts in restore.